# Jibx 1.2.5 fails with java 7

Tags: java, jibx

I am migrating my project from Java 6 to Java 7. We use JibX extensively in our project. Till now we were using JibX 1.2.2 and everything was working fine.

But due to migration to Java 7 we upgraded from JibX 1.2.2 to JibX 1.2.5. Also we are using jibx-maven-plugin version 1.2.5. But with the upgradation of JibX, we are facing some issues now.

When built with target 1.7 and JibX 1.2.5, JibX is building the jar file but during aspectJ weaving, getting the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) on project gdsmodel-aspects: Compiler errors:
[ERROR] abort ABORT -- (ClassFormatException) Index 12895 into constant pool (size:12371) is invalid
[ERROR] Index 12895 into constant pool (size:12371) is invalid
[ERROR] org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Index 12895 into constant pool (size:12371) is invalid
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.getConstant(ConstantPool.java:66)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.getConstantUtf8(ConstantPool.java:220)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.Attribute.readAttribute(Attribute.java:111)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.AttributeUtils.readAttributes(AttributeUtils.java:19)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.FieldOrMethod.<init>(FieldOrMethod.java:97)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.Field.<init>(Field.java:82)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readFields(ClassParser.java:206)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:141)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.Utility.makeJavaClass(Utility.java:467)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.UnwovenClassFile.getJavaClass(UnwovenClassFile.java:68)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addClassFile(BcelWeaver.java:455)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:402)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:893)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:249)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:248)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.AbstractAjcCompiler.execute(AbstractAjcCompiler.java:549)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

So I turned on the "verify" flag in jibx-maven-plugin (which specifies "Control flag for verifying generated/modified classes with BCEL.") when jibx fails with the following error :

```
[exec] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jibx:jibx-maven-plugin:1.2.5:bind (jibx-bind) on project gdsmodel: Invalid this class index 6218 in constant pool in class file com/g2switch/dto/passive/
JiBX_passive_v24_0MungeAdapter -> [Help 1]
```

Only one thing that I noticed (and is bugging me) is JibX is generating an "JiBX_passive_v24_0MungeAdapter.class" of size almost 14MB and the verification is failing in this class.

```
[exec] Verification failure on class com.g2switch.dto.passive.JiBX_passive_v24_0MungeAdapter
```

But keeping every thing same when I just change the target from 1.7 to 1.6 everything works fine [also using JibX 1.2.5].

N.B : We have a project which has many binding files (> 150 and also each file contains huge amount of data). The problem occurs while building this project. But when I include fewer bindings (< 20) then the problem disappears. So is this problem due to the large munge adapter file generated by JibX, when large amount of bindings are involved? If this is the cause then how to solve it?

Comment: Any solutions for this ?? I have encountered the same issue with JIBX 1.2.5 version and JDK 1.8 with more than 40+ jibx binding file and Munge Adpater file is close to 3.5 mb and not able parse this file.